# php: newbie modrewrite question

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm having a little issue with modrewrite under php.
this is inside my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.html$ test.php
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
```

it works nicely with test.html -> test.php
but i'm getting an 404 error when trying to acceses my domain like www.domain.com/index.html
althought it's the same structure and should work .. :/
when using www.domain.com only it works.

any idea what's wrong with using index.php -> index.html?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like index.php doesn't exist.

When you go to http://www.domain.com it is going to hit index.html (or index.php) and in the case of index.html it WONT fire your rewrite rule (as the request uri is / or empty string)